# AWS S3 CLI error when file name contains parentheses

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, child-process

I'm running on Node and using `child_process` In order to perform `aws s3 cp` command.

```
import { spawn, ChildProcess } from 'child_process';
/// some logic

const s3Cp = (source: string, target: string) => {
  logger.info(`starting s3 sync. source : ${source}, target ${target}`);
  const childProcess = new SpawnTimeout('aws', ['s3', 'cp', `"${source}"`, `"${target}"`, '--only-show-errors'], S3_SYNC_TIMEOUT, 's3 sync');
  return childProcess.exec();
};
```

and I encounter an error in case a file name parentheses.

For example `aws s3 cp image_compressions/1636550256772_W_-_Wonton_noodles_(NEW)-01.png  s3://bucketname/image/W_-_Wonton_noodles_(NEW)-01.png --only-show-errors`

I tried resolving it by added quotes to the file names, like in the code sample above, which results in

`aws s3 cp "image_compressions/1636550256772_W_-_Wonton_noodles_(NEW)-01.png"  "s3://bucketname/image/W_-_Wonton_noodles_(NEW)-01.png" --only-show-errors`

But when running I get a different error -

```
usage: aws s3 cp <LocalPath> <S3Uri> or <S3Uri> <LocalPath> or <S3Uri> <S3Uri>
Error: Invalid argument type
```

Please advise how I can resolve the issue.

Comment: Which version of AWS CLI do you have? Which type od OS and shell do you have? I tried your command `aws s3 cp "image_compressions/1636550256772_W_-_Wonton_noodles_(NEW)-01.png"  "s3://<my-bucket>/W_-_Wonton_noodles_(NEW)-01.png"` and everything went fine so I assume it is problem with your environment, not with command itself.

Comment: FYI, rather than spawning the AWS CLI, you could use the AWS SDK for Node.js to directly call Amazon S3.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I believe that copyObject allows to copy objects between buckets. I need to copy it locally and then back to the bucket.

Comment: Yes, you can do that with the AWS SDK: [Uploading and Downloading Files in S3 with Node.js – MyDatahack](https://www.mydatahack.com/uploading-and-downloading-files-in-s3-with-node-js/)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein this thing is I need to upload image file to S3, and could not find an example of that.

Comment: There is an example in the article I linked.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the upload works but the file in S3 cannot be opened.

Comment: What do you mean "cannot be opened"? What did you do? What happened? Did you modify the contents of the file between the download and the upload?